# How can I check that UPDATE statement finished in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I use QuestDB and when I update the table using

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = 1
WHERE col1 = 2
```

sometimes I see `col1` still having stale value for a bit of time in the next selects, e.g. this returns a non-empty result

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE col1 = 2
```

As far as I understand it's a feature of WAL table that updates are async. Is there a way to check that the update is completed?